# Are strings anagram

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, interview-questions

This is a question from the book "[Cracking the Coding Interview](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/0984782850/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=0106d-21&camp=3638&creative=24630&linkCode=as2&creativeASIN=0984782850&linkId=6bf430d6374ca7ffb9f2cac081fc2d31)".

> Write a method to decide if two strings are anagrams or not

I think interviewer will not be convinced with this solution because here it is no test of logic. Please help me to optimise this solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

std::string toLower(std::string str)
{
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),
                   [](unsigned char ch) { return std::tolower(ch); });
    return str;
}

bool areAnagrams(std::string& str1, std::string& str2)
{

    str1 = toLower(str1);
    str2 = toLower(str2);
    std::sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());
    std::sort(str2.begin(), str2.end());

    if (str1.compare(str2) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string str1, str2;
    std::cout << "Enter String 1: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str1);
    std::cout << "Enter String 2: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str2);
    bool res = areAnagrams(str1, str2);
    if (res == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Strings are anagram\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Strings are not anagram\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I think interviewer will not be convinced with this solution because here it is no test of logic.

I'm not sure what you mean by "because here it is no test of logic," but if what you mean is "because I found this puzzle too easy," then *good!* That's what the interviewer is likely to be hiring for: people who solve problems easily and quickly.

When you get an easy problem in an interview, that may be a sign that the interviewer is trying to judge your *coding skills* rather than your *algorithmic/research skills*. So make sure your *code* is as polished as (reasonably) possible.

- `areAnagrams` takes its parameters by non-const reference. This is probably a bug. The interviewer will ask you to "explain your choice." Your answer should be something like "oops, I forgot to remove the `&`." (This reflects a little badly on your coding skills.)
- `if (res == 1)` is a *very* strange way to test for boolean `true`-ness. It would be less unusual, but still a minor yellow flag, to test for `if (res == true)` or `if (res)`. It would be *good* to remove the useless variable and test directly for `if (areAnagrams(str1, str2))`.

---

Similarly, in the body of `areAnagrams`, you have written

```
if (str1.compare(str2) == 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

This is a *very* long-winded and confusing way of writing

```
return str1 == str2;
```

and is kind of a big deal. The interviewer is not looking to hire people who write eight lines of convoluted code when one line of simple code would do the job.

You also have an extra blank line at the beginning of `areAnagrams`; this shows a possible tendency toward sloppiness. The interviewer is not looking to hire people who might "typo" their way into a bug.

---

On the plus side, your definition of `toLower` is very good!  The interviewer might ask you to explain why you took by value instead of by `const&`. The interviewer might ask you whether the line `return str;` makes a copy of the string or whether the copy is elided. (Trick question! The answer is "neither.")

Comment: `The answer is "neither."` Why does NRVO not work in this case?

Comment: [Funny you should ask!](https://cppcon2018.sched.com/event/FnL2/rvo-is-harder-than-it-looks-the-story-of-wreturn-std-move) NRVO works by constructing the object `str` directly into `toLower`'s return slot. But in this case, `toLower` does not control where `str` gets constructed (because `str` is a *parameter*). The result is that `str` will be *moved* into the return slot — neither copied nor copy-elided, but *moved*.

Answer (score 10):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### `bool` is not `int`

The `bool` type is a full-fledged first class type in C++.  If I were an interviewer reading this code, I'd be perplexed:

```
bool res = areAnagrams(str1, str2);
if (res == 1)
{
    std::cout << "Strings are anagram\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Strings are not anagram\n";
}
```

A similar thing is being done here:

```
if (str1.compare(str2) == 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

First, we are comparing a `bool` to `1` (an `int`) which is odd enough.  Next, if we're returning the result of the comparison, why don't we *return the result of the comparison*?

```
return !str1.compare(str2);
```

Better still:

```
return str1 == str2;
```

### Understand references

The prototype of the `toLower` function is this:

```
std::string toLower(std::string str);
bool areAnagrams(std::string& str1, std::string& str2);
```

So reading this, the `toLower` makes a *copy* of its argument and `areAnagrams` uses references.  However, the first few lines of the latter function are these:

```
str1 = toLower(str1);
str2 = toLower(str2);
```

There's little point to making copies and then assigning the copy back to the original.  What I would recommend instead is to have `toLower` take a reference and `areAnagrams` pass by value.  That way, we have a much more logical interface in which `toLower` modifies the passed string but `areAnagrams` does not.

### Use `auto` to simplify code

The better choice for `res` in `main` would be to declare it `auto` instead of explicitly naming `bool`.

### Consider the use of `locale`

Rather than writing your own `toLower`, why not use the one in `<locale>`?  Here's how that might look:

```
auto& facet{std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(std::locale())};
facet.tolower(&str1.front(), &str1.back());
facet.tolower(&str2.front(), &str2.back());
```

### Use better naming

The function `toLower` is a good name because (with the suggested change mentioned above) it says what it actually does.  However, `res` is not a good name and it's not necessary to have a separate variable anyway.  Instead of this strange construction:

```
bool res = areAnagrams(str1, str2);
if (res == 1)
{
    std::cout << "Strings are anagram\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Strings are not anagram\n";
}
```

I would probably instead have written this:

```
std::cout << "Strings " << (areAnagrams(str1, str2) ? "are" : "are not")
          <<  " anagrams\n";
```

Although, as @TobySpeight points out in a comment, better for the purposes of translating the string into another language would be to keep the strings intact.  One way to do that:

```
std::cout << (areAnagrams(str1, str2) ? "Strings are anagrams\n"
                  : "Strings are not anagrams\n");
```

### Declare variables each on a separate line

Clarify variable declaration by declaring each one on a single line. See [Guideline ES.10](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-name-one)

### Consider namespace or `static`

During an interview, I'd probably ask why you chose not to encapsulate the functions in a namespace, and why the functions are not `static`.  There are arguments both ways for each of those; be aware of what they are and be able to explain and defend your choices.

Comment: `std::string::compare` returns <0, 0, or >0, so the first part of your answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jamesdlin: it was missing a `!` which is now corrected.

Comment: I meant that the whole "`bool` is not `int`" premise is misdirected ("we are comparing a `bool` to `0`..."; no, it's comparing `int` to `0`).  Regarding your edit: I personally dislike `!str.compare(str)` for the same reason as you originally give: `bool` is not `int`, and `!` on an `int` seems weird.

Comment: First, within `main` we have `if (res == 1)` which is comparing a `bool` to an `int`.  Second, I agree that `!str1.compare(str2)` is not very good, which is why what I recommend instead is `return str1 == str2;` which I suspect we both agree is the most clear and straightforward way to do it.

Comment: I've edited the answer for hopefully improved clarity.  Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Under "Use better naming", you go a bit further than I would.  There's an argument against breaking strings into pieces like that - it's an anti-pattern that hinders translation.  When your program is likely to be translated (and in an interview you do want to demonstrate that you can work with translators), it's usually better to keep strings whole - this is where C-style format strings can be valuable: `std::printf(areAnagrams(str1, str2) ? "%s is an anagram of %s\n" : "%s is not an anagram of %s\n", str1.c_str(), str2.c_str());`

Comment: @TobySpeight: It's a good point -- I've updated my answer to talk about translation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You know, when deciding whether you have anagrams, you are generally only interested in alpha-numeric characters, the rest are disregarded.

Next, making extraneous copies is generally a bad idea. So, accept a constant view and don't make a copy.

When you accept a mutable reference, be sure that it's obvious from the function-name and arity that it's a mutable reference.

If you can, avoid external linkage. It promotes inlining and avoids unfortunate name-clashes.

Finally, a faster algorithm is normally preferable:

```
bool isAnagram(std::string_view a, std::string_view b) noexcept {
    unsigned counts[1ULL + (unsigned char)-1] = {};
    for (unsigned char c : a)
        ++counts[std::tolower(c)];
    for (unsigned char c : b)
        --counts[std::tolower(c)];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < std::size(counts); ++i)
        if (counts[i] && std::isalnum(i))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: While this may be a faster algorithm, is it a clearer algorithm?  I think that for an interview, it may be better to write for clarity.

Comment: @Edward Yes, I would say so.

Comment: (2) This code is different from OP's, it ignores non-alnum characters. (3) It's actually slower for short string, as it allocates an array of ~256 ints.

Comment: Why `int map[]`?  `unsigned map[]` will likely give the right answer in most cases for extremely long strings even if a bucket wraps around, without any signed-overflow UB.  (If you can rule out long strings, `unsigned char map[]` cuts the cache footprint by 4 on most modern C++ implementations, and allows faster checking for non-zero buckets on targets where the compiler can use SIMD for the final loop.)  I was going to say `uint8_t`, but you don't need to stop the code from working on implementations without uint8_t, like some DSPs where char is 32 bits.

Comment: @user176443: (2) Yes, it's different, but the difference is only in a small part, and there's a reason. (3) Did you time it? Especially as the OPs code allocates a new `std::string` both times `toLower()` is called, and `std::sort()` isn't cheap either?

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, hm, there's actually no reason to use a signed type, yes, so I'll Change that.

Comment: @user17... If you're checking *all* characters, then check if lengths are equal as an early-out before doing anything else.  But *allocating* 1kiB on the stack is basically free; literally 1 instruction.  Zeroing it has some  small cost.  Touching it might cause some cache misses, but store-forwarding might manage to hide a lot of the cost of that (i.e. the reloads don't have to wait for the stores to commit); only 32x 32-byte stores, so maybe 32 store-buffer entries for zeroing it.  The load part of each increment should forward from the zeroing, but the store part uses another buffer.

Comment: Haswell has 42 store buffer entries (https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/5/), so for short strings even if the stack memory was cold in cache, this algo could return a true/false result without waiting for any of the stores to commit to L1d cache.  If you want to optimize more for potentially-short strings, check if the strings are less than 256 chars and use an array of `uint8_t` for a smaller cache footprint